# How can i print the outputs from a for loop on different lines rather than in a single line? Python 3

Tags: python-3.7

i have only started to learn programming and now i am learning for loop in python
I want to print my outputs in different files like:

```
> 2 4 8 6 10 12 . .
```

rather than printing like:

```
> 2
  24 
  246 
  2468
  246810
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add end=' ' to print of python
example:

```
for i in range(50):
    print(i, end=' ')
```